# "Python has stopped working" error when instantiating subclass of QStyledItemDelegate twice

Tags: python, pyqt5

I have the following code to align text of QTableWidget's column.

```
import sys

from PyQt5           import QtWidgets, QtCore
from PyQt5.QtCore    import Qt
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import QApplication, QTableWidget, QTableWidgetItem, QStyledItemDelegate

class AlignRightDelegate(QStyledItemDelegate):
    def initStyleOption(self, option, index):
        super(AlignRightDelegate, self).initStyleOption(option, index)
        option.displayAlignment = Qt.AlignRight

class Table(QTableWidget):
    def __init__(self, data, alignColumns = 1, *args):
        QTableWidget.__init__(self, *args)
        self.setRowCount(len(data))
        self.setColumnCount(3)

        self.setData(data)
        self.resizeColumnsToContents()

        for colIndex in range(1, 1 + alignColumns):
            print("Align Column [", colIndex, "]", sep="")
            self.setItemDelegateForColumn(colIndex, AlignRightDelegate())

    def setData(self, data): 
        horizontalHeaders = []
        for m, rowContent in enumerate(data):
            for n, cellContent in enumerate(data[m]):
                if (m == 0):
                    horizontalHeaders.append(cellContent)
                else:
                    self.setItem(m - 1, n, QTableWidgetItem(cellContent))
        self.setHorizontalHeaderLabels(horizontalHeaders)

if __name__ == "__main__":
    data = [["col1", "col2", "col3"],
            [   "1",   "１", "a"],
            [  "-1",   "２", "b"], 
            [   "0",   "３", "c"]]
    print("python QTableWidgetAlignRight.py[ <AlignColumnCount=1]")
    app = QApplication(sys.argv)
    table = Table(data, int(sys.argv[1])) if (len(sys.argv) > 1) else Table(data)
    table.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

If I execute the above code with `python QTableWidgetAlignRight.py 1` it **sort of works** as it should as shown below with **col2** aligned to the right **but apparently to the top also**:

[image: Works]

However when I execute the same code with `python QTableWidgetAlignRight.py 2` where I try to align 2 columns to the right, I ran into `Python has stopped working error`. The following screenshot is actually on my Japanese Windows OS (Win 10 Pro 20H2 (OS Build 19402.1165))

[image: Doesn't Work (Error Message in Japanese)]

However I searched the net for the same error message in English and I found a screenshot albeit not due to my code above (burrowed from this page: [Python has stopped working](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47828821/python-has-stopped-working/47829006)).

[image: Same Error Message in English]

So what is the correct way of aligning 2 columns of my QTableWidget (without an error and without aligning to the top vertically)? Also is this a bug in PyQt5?

For your information, I am using the following: `Python 3.7.6`, `conda 4.8.2`, `pyqt 5.9.2 py37h6538335_2`. For column alignment, I looked at this for reference: [How to align all items in a column to center in QTableWidget](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52644371/how-to-align-all-items-in-a-column-to-center-in-qtablewidget)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Due to the way python and PyQt keep references to objects, only ***one*** *unparented* and *unreferenced* delegate can theoretically be set for each view.

But, while it is possible to set *one* delegate like this, it should not be done: delegates should always have a persistent reference or valid parent since the view does *not* take ownership of the delegate (see the docs for all [`setItemDelegate*`](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qabstractitemview.html#setItemDelegate) functions).

Also, considering that you are using the same delegate for multiple columns, there's no point in creating more than one.

```
    self.alignDelegate = AlignRightDelegate(self)
    for colIndex in range(1, 1 + alignColumns):
        print("Align Column [", colIndex, "]", sep="")
        self.setItemDelegateForColumn(colIndex, self.alignDelegate)
```

Note that you could either use the parent argument (`self`) *or* create an instance attribute:

```
self.alignDelegate = AlignRightDelegate()
# or
alignDelegate = AlignRightDelegate(self)
```

Using both, though, is not an issue, and specifying the parent is a good choice anyway when dealing with Qt objects.
In any case, at least one of the methods above should *always* be used.

<sup>You get a wrong alignment because you only set the *horizontal* alignment: use `option.displayAlignment = Qt.AlignRight | Qt.AlignVCenter`.</sup>

Comment: Are there typos in that first paragraph? As it stands, it seems contradictory.

Comment: @ekhumoro maybe I should rephrase that: what I meant is that in PyQt it is possible to use an unreferenced delegate instance, but just one: as soon as it is attempted to create another one for the same view, the program will freeze. So, while it technically works, it should not be done.

Comment: So it should be "one" rather than "an". But still, I feel the advice should always be to keep a reference - particularly when the docs state that Qt doesn't take ownership. Saying it "can" be done in PyQt suggests that it's explicitly supported in some sense, rather than being a mere implementation detail.

Comment: @ekhumoro good point, again. I've updated the answer, I believe it should be more clear now.